# Toggle the names of two specific files (or folders)

Tags: windows, vbscript, batch-file

I need to toggle the names of two specific files existing at a specific path on the local drive and wonder if a .bat or a .vbs can achieve that.

In other words executing the script **once** swaps "File A" with "File B" ("C:\Path A\File A.txt" with "C:\Path A\File B.txt") and running it **once more** will swap them again.

I am also curious to know if the same can be done:

1) In this situation -->> "C:\Some Path\File A.txt" and "D:\Some Other Path\File B.txt"

and

2) If instead of two files I want to toggle two folders.

Comment: As a warning, using edits to insult people who tried to help you is completely unacceptable here. Do not do this again.

Comment: Is there something additional that you need the script to do in order to have it work for you?

Comment: @ Brad Larson: And the patronizing tone seems to be completely acceptable... Frankly I am the one who feels insulted here!

Comment: @ Rob Huston: Thanks for your kind **and detailed** support. I will do some more tests/research and will get back to you :)

Answer (score 3):

Create the following batch file and name it whatever you want.  I'm using the name "myRename.bat".

```
:: myRename.bat
@echo off
SETLOCAL

:: verify the first file exists
if not exist "%~1" ( echo ERROR: File not found "%~1" & goto endofscript )

:: verify the second file exists
if not exist "%~2" ( echo ERROR: File not found "%~2" & goto endofscript )

:: Create a guaranteed unique string for temporarily naming one file
set instance=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%
set instance=%instance%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%
set instance=%instance%-%RANDOM%

:: rename the first file to a temporary name
ren "%~1" "%~nx1.%instance%"
:: rename the second file to the first file name
ren "%~2" "%~nx1"
:: rename teh first file to the second file name
ren "%~1.%instance%" "%~nx2"

:endofscript
```

Assuming these two files exist in this path:

- c:\temp\Rename test\File A.txt
- c:\temp\Rename test\File B.txt

Then you can run the command below and they will swap names:

```
myRename "c:\temp\Rename test\File A.txt" "c:\temp\Rename test\File B.txt"
```

If either File A or File B are not found, that error is reported on screen and the process stops.